# Xenserver 6.2 has trouble booting Linux live discs

Tags: xen, xenserver

I recently installed Xencenter 6.2. I was able to install and configure a Windows VM. However, whenever I boot different Linux distros after the boot menu (syslinux or whatever) the disc always locks up. I tried Fedora 19, RHEL 6, and gparted. I get the feeling that it must be a xenserver or BIOS configuration issue. The processor is an Intel E5-2609 which supports VT-x. Any ideas?

Comment: A bounty? This is really the type of question that needs a lot of back and forth troubleshooting -- "try this, try that", come back, get an answer/output, try something else, and on and on. A bounty isn't going to get you a definitive answer. Maybe come to Root Access or The Comms Room on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) for help.

Comment: I didn't know about that. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Linux Virtual Machines are Unable to Boot from DVD on XenServer](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132039),
although for XenServer 5.5/5,6, might still pertain here :

> Unlike Microsoft Windows, which uses device drivers for
>   paravirtualization, Linux virtual machines have a paravirtualized
>   kernel. During the installation of Linux, it is actually running as a
>   Hardware-Assisted Virtual Machine (HVM) and has access to DVD just
>   like Windows. Once the Linux installation is complete, a Xen kernel is
>   swapped in. However, as the paravirtualization is kernel based, this
>   causes issues with accessing the DVD on boot, as the kernel is not
>   loaded.
>
> To allow the Linux virtual machine to boot from DVD, the virtual
>   machine should be set to start in Recovery Mode, as shown in the
>   following screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: More possible info: [This thread](http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=309745) suggested adding `clocksource=jiffies` to the kernel boot parameters. The poster's answer was that only CentOS Live seems to work on Xenserver.

Comment: That worked for CentOS but I couldn't get it work on any other distros just like the poster...

Comment: There must be some deficiency in the way Xenserver handles live CDs. I don't know what's different about CentOS Live, but its working on Xenserver is probably just a coincidence. If I had to guess, I would say a wrong implementation in Xenserver of the emulation of some hardware instruction which the CentOS boot just happens not to use.

Comment: What I don't get is, I used Xencenter in the past and never had these issues. I didn't do anything unique after the install. This should just be working... SO maybe it's my hardware?

Comment: If it's new hardware different from before, that's possible. Or your version of Xencenter is now more recent, so going back to the old one will fix it, if it's a recently-introduced bug.